# Can't delete files from Xcode

Tags: xcode, ide, xcode7

I'm new to Xcode and I looked at the other threads with the same problem
and did't find an answer.

I opened few projects in Xcode and i wanted to delete them. I deleted the folder of the projects and all the files but I still see them when i press right click on Xcode.

[image: the problem]

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete your project it is ok that you can see it there, because it just shows last opened projects. (it does not mean rheese projects are still there and working). I hope this was helpful.